# Combine lists that meet specific criteria, and filter them out

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am trying to manage a matrix in Mathematica that has the general architecture

`{{a1,b1},{a2,b2}...}`

I would like to combine all of the lists that have the same the first value and transform it to a new list of lists of the second values,

For example,
If I have the list 
`{{1,2},{1,5},{1,30},{2,6},{3,8},{3,30},{4,1}}`

I would like the output to be
`{{2,5,30},{6},{8,30},{1}}`

I would then like to remove any of the list elements that contain only 1 value

So that my final output would be
`{{2,5,30},{8,30}}`

I am still new to data manipulation in mathematica and really do not know where to begin on this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
Values @ DeleteCases[{_}] @ GroupBy[
    {{1,2},{1,5},{1,30},{2,6},{3,8},{3,30},{4,1}},
    First->Last
]
```

> {{2, 5, 30}, {8, 30}}

or [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy)

```
DeleteCases[{_}] @ GatherBy[
    {{1,2},{1,5},{1,30},{2,6},{3,8},{3,30},{4,1}},
    First
][[All, All, 2]]
```

> {{2, 5, 30}, {8, 30}}